# capybara find and save text value from a page

Tags: regex, automation, web-scraping, capybara

i am in the process of writing a Capybara Automation suite. one thing that i am trying to do is extract a value between the td tags from the html source

```
<td class="table-column-data">CB/AE9999XX/A001</td>
```

i.e. find and extract the value CB/AE9999XX/A001 then save it into a variable to use later on.

i hope you can help

thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
saved_text = find("td.table-column-data").text
```

Will get the text from the element - obviously the selector passed needs to select a unique element, which will depend on the surrounding html

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below mentioned way to extract and save the value in a variable:

```
extractedValue = find('.table-column-data').text
```

This will fetch the text "CB/AE9999XX/A001" and store it in the variable "extractedValue".

Apart from this, you can also extract the text using jquery as shown below:

```
extractedValue = page.evaluate_script("$('.table-column-data').text()")
```

Hope this helps :)